# MySQL Administrator asks for password every time

Tags: password, mysql

I have instlaled MySQL Administrator and it works fine, except one annoying thing. Every time i select a table and click 'Edit Table Data' from context menu, it prompts for password.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: An Alternative Way Is To Create An Alias example > alias cmsql='mysql -u root -p1' < So When Ever You Type cmsql (Connect MySQL ) It Will Connect To MySQL Without Password Cauzz Its Defined In An Alias , Where As My Password Is "1"

Answer (score 4):

I haven't used this particular tool, but I'll take a guess that it reads from `~/.my.cnf` like most utilities that talk to MySQL do.

Try creating a file in your home directory, named `.my.cnf`, with the following:

```
[client]
user = USERNAME
password = PASSWORD
```

Replace USERNAME and PASSWORD accordingly and give it another shot.

To check it's working, you should then be able to run the `mysql` client program from the terminal and it should log right in with no prompt.

Comment: But I connect to many servers, and have separate credentials for each. Also, storing a password in plain text under home dir is not very secure. However, I find that there is Tools > Preferences > General Options > Store connection passwords which will save encrypted password and prevent from retyping password every time, but it still pops up every time you click ` 'Edit Table Data` and you need to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

Are you logging in from root account ?
create a root account by using MYSQL Administrator
with debian-sys-maint account whose username and password are present in 
/etc/mysql/debian.cnf

see if it helps